# SUM as condition when joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

I have this query which counts the amount of return invoices I had per month:

```
SELECT MONTH(ORIN.DocDate) mes, COUNT(*) tot
FROM ORIN
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, ORIN.DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 12
GROUP BY MONTH(ORIN.DocDate)
```

Now I need to get only the invoices on which the amount of items is more than 100. For this I must join another table (invoice items):

```
INNER JOIN RIN1 ON ORIN.DocEntry = RIN1.DocEntry
```

And somewhere I'll put this (must be a SUM because one invoice can have many items):

```
WHERE SUM(RIN1.Quantity) > 100
```

Problem is I don't know how to make this query. My last attempt was as below but it's not bringing the right values:

```
SELECT MONTH(ORIN.DocDate) mes, COUNT(*) tot
FROM ORIN
INNER JOIN RIN1 ON ORIN.DocEntry = RIN1.DocEntry
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, ORIN.DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 12
GROUP BY MONTH(ORIN.DocDate)
HAVING SUM(RIN1.Quantity) > 100
```

Comment: Which database/flavor or SQL are you using?

Comment: I do not think you need to use `HAVING` clause in your query since the `Quantity` itself explains the number, may just add `AND RIN1.Quantity>100` to your `Where` clause

Comment: Problem is one invoice can have more than one item and RIN1 is one item for each record.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider only invoices for which exist more than 100 items. Two methods:

**1) Count the items with a correlated subquery:**

```
select month(docdate) mes, count(*) tot
from orin
where datediff(month, docdate, getdate()) <= 12
and 
(
  select sum(quantity)
  from rin1
  where rin1.docentry = orin.docentry
) > 100
group by month(docdate);
```

**2) Look up the list of invoices with more than 100 items:**

```
select month(docdate) mes, count(*) tot
from orin
where datediff(month, docdate, getdate()) <= 12
and docentry in
(
  select docentry
  from rin1
  group by docentry
  having sum(quantity) > 100
)
group by month(docdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter invoices with more than 100 items, as represented by `RIN1.Quantity`.

Simply add the filter in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT MONTH(ORIN.DocDate) mes, COUNT(*) tot
FROM ORIN
INNER JOIN RIN1 ON ORIN.DocEntry = RIN1.DocEntry
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, ORIN.DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 12
  AND RIN1.Quantity > 100
GROUP BY MONTH(ORIN.DocDate)
```

Comment: Problem is one invoice can have more than one item and RIN1 is one item for each record